# Access violation when attempting to access object member variables in an array

Tags: c++, pointers

My program/assignment, a "zoo simulation" involves dynamic arrays [can't use vectors] of different species animal objects that inherit from the Animal base class.  But my problem seems to be very simple (I hope):

I've been using the construction

```
Animal **arr = new Animal*[10];
```

but reading `arr[0]->getAge()` causes an access violation.

I'm trying to simultaneously understand pointers but also maybe get the code right pre-complete understanding because of a deadline.

I've tried

```
*arr = new Animal[10]
```

but run into problems when I want to add/change objects in the array, or delete an array. Perhaps the

** new *

only works with certain variable types and not class objects.  I can set up an array with the

```
*arr = new Animal[10];
```

formation but then when I try to set something like

```
 arr[05] = to a new Tiger object,
```

nothing changes, so I'm hitting a wall.

Basically I need to initialize an array of Animal objects, and then add inherited class objects to the array. Thanks for any insight and apologies for my newbishness.

Answer (score 3):

In

```
Animal **arr = new Animal*[10];
```

`Animal **arr` declares a pointer to a pointer. `new Animal*[10]` allocates 10 pointers to `Animal`s. These 10 pointers are uninitialzed and don't point anywhere safe to use.

```
arr[0]->getAge();
```

gets the firs of these 10 pointers and attempts to use what it points at. Since it doesn't point at a valid `Animal` anything can happen. In this case it appears that the program crashes. This is one of the better outcomes because it makes the mistake instantly noticeable.

Now assuming `Tiger` derives from `Animal`

```
class Tiger: public Animal
{
    // definition of Tiger
}
```

then you can later

```
arr[0] = new Tiger;
```

to point the first of the 10 pointers at a valid instance of `Tiger` and then you can

```
arr[0]->getAge();
```

When you are done, don't forget to `delete` all of the `Animal`s and to `delete[]` `arr`.

Sidenote:

Don't write code like this. It is extremely fault-prone. Instead take advantage of Standard Library containers like `std::vector` and prefer smart pointers like `std::unique_ptr` to manage the program's dynamic memory. Example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Animal>> arr;
```

Makes a resizable array of `Animal`s that will all automatically be deleted when `arr` is no longer needed and goes out of scope.

Adding a `Tiger` would look like

```
arr.push_back(std::make_unique<Tiger>());
```

This LOOKS more cumbersome, but it saves you from having to find the exact places in the code where you must `delete` your resources and make absolutely certain that they are `delete`d.

Answer (score 0):

You've allocated an array of pointers but you have not actually allocated any objects for those pointers to point at. So `arr[0]->...` is undefined behavior.